# What's the best housecarl for a stealthy mage with little health?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My character is very sneaky with a lot of magic. My biggest flaw is I have almost no health and I'm trying to figure out which is the best housecarl to get. I'm looking for someone tanky. That way, if I'm discovered, I can use the housecarl as a human shield.

Comment: This will be closed on the basis of being opinion based. You need to reword your question to state something like: What are the stats of all of the housecarls. That is NOT opinion based and will be okay.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the [wiki](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Housecarl), all housecarls have the same stats, including their health, stamina, and armor skills. There isn't a specific "tanky" character to choose.

Comment: You should pay closer attention to your own source material.  While most Housecarls are listed as Warriors, [Valdimar](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Valdimar_(Hearthfire)) is listed as a Sorcerer's skill set.  But in any case I'm not sure I'd bring a Heavy Armor type with me when stealth is required....